# Extraction of Mainframe datasets used in the jobs which are scheduled in TWS

Tags: sas, jcl, tws

I am looking to extract the list of datasets used in the Jobs which are scheduled in TWS. Can you please help me on this?
Here is the sample example

```
owner name ,Jobname ,dataset name
CAXXXXXXX   PADLSHX  EBEU.XXXX
```

The execution can be either in JCL OR JCL with SAS, please let me know if there is any program which results the above ask.

Comment: _If I remember well from last century, when I worked on mainframe,_ TWS is a system to schedule jobs written in Job Control Language (JCL). __Is your question__ "How can I access the meta data in TWS to extract this information?" __or is it__ "Does anyone have a program that extract this type of information from JCL code?"

Comment: the second one, is there any program in jcl or jcl with sas to get this info?

Comment: I have written that kind of programs in the past, but am not sure I still have them.